# not able to get the last index inside foreach knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-mvc

I am not able to get the last of observableArray index inside foreach in gsp page as below

```
<!-- ko foreach: $data.audienceInformation.IndivisualUsers -->
  <span data-bind="html:$index()"></span>        //Here index is coming correctly
  <span data-bind="html:$last"></span>           //i want last index here
  <span data-bind="html:$data+','"></span>
<!-- /ko -->
```

This is my JSON data

```
{
    "AccountMessagesHistory": {
        "audienceInformation": {
            "Accounts": ["DHL"],
            "IndivisualUsers": ["fashangxue8@163.com"]
        },
        "documentInformation": ["Name: ",
               "Title: <p>aa</p>",
               "Description: <p>aa</p>",
               "Document Type: text",
               "This document belongs (creator/last modifier) to: b2b:cpqadmin@compaq.com",
               "This document is published for the language: en_US",
               "This document was created on: Mon Mar 03 03:15:09 MST 2014",
               "This document was last modified on: Mon Mar 03 03:15:09 MST 2014",
               "This document is a text document",
               "This document will be available from: Mon Mar 03 00:00:00 MST 2014",
               "This document will be available until: Tue Mar 03 00:00:00 MST 2015",
               "This document is available under message feature card"],
        "documentHistory": ["User ID: b2b:cpqadmin@xyz.com      Name: HP Admin,ITG      Modified On: Mon Mar 03 03:15:09 MST 2014"]
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using knockout 2.0.0? I think $index wasn't release until 2.1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `$last`, use the `.length` of the array:

```
<span data-bind="text: ko.utils.unwrapObservable($parent.audienceInformation.IndivisualUsers).length - 1"></span>
```

Comment: To use `ko.unwrap` in KO 2.1.0 you need to declare it `if (typeof ko.unwrap === 'undefined') {
    ko.unwrap = ko.utils.unwrapObservable;
}`

Comment: You're right, I changed it to `ko.utils.unwrapObservable`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using knockout 2.1.0, you can use:

```
<span data-bind="text: $parent.audienceInformation.IndivisualUsers().length - 1"></span>
```

or

```
<span data-bind="text: ko.utils.unwrapObservable($parent.audienceInformation.IndivisualUsers).length - 1"></span>
```